# Excel formula for convertiny monthly targets to weekly ones

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have the monthly sales targets for a company for 2015 (not linear) and would like to convert them into weekly targets. I am unsure how to come up with a formula which deals with overlapping days (where some days of a week are in one month and the others overflow into the next).

I found something [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/627101-converting-data-monthly-weekly.html) which describes the problem, but I have little knowledge of excel formulae and cannot understand what has been done to solve it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Your question is very vague. Are you asking for algorithm? Or how to program it in Excel? Or both? I could help you with excel but only if you specify what task you are trying to accomplish and ideally provide some example source data and expected output.

Comment: @Taosique I'm asking for an explained Excel solution. What about the task do you not understand- have you looked at the link? It is described better there, feel free to use arbitrary data

Comment: Should the weekends be taken into account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say, you have your monthly targets in `Sheet1`:

[image: Sheet1]

```
Column A:A     2015-01-01, 2015-02-01, 2015-03-01 ...
Column B:B     =DAY(DATE(YEAR($A2),MONTH($A2)+1,0))
Column C:C     monthly target values
Column D:D     =$C2/$B2
```

Then in `Sheet2` you can calculate your weekly targets (I assume columns `A:A`, `B:B` and `C:C` don't need explanation):

[image: Sheet2]

```
Column D:D    =DATE(YEAR($B2),MONTH($B2),1)
Column E:E    =DATE(YEAR($C2),MONTH($C2),1)
Column F:F    =7-$G2
Column G:G    =IF($D2<>$E2,DAY($C2),0)
Column H:H    =$F2*SUMIF(Sheet1!$A:$A,$D2,Sheet1!$D:$D)+$G2*SUMIF(Sheet1!$A:$A,$E2,Sheet1!$D:$D)
```

To take in account only working days (without Saturday and Sunday) change the following formulas:

```
Sheet1 Column B:B    =NETWORKDAYS($A2,DATE(YEAR($A2),MONTH($A2)+1,0))
Sheet2 Column F:F    =5-$G2
Sheet2 Column G:G    =IF($D2<>$E2,MAX(DAY($C2)-2,0),0)
```

Comment: I think this answers it perfectly, thank you so much. What would I have to change in order to exclude weekends?

Comment: sorry I'm terrible at Excel- how do I get B:B and C:C in sheet 2 from week numbers?

Comment: Just type the first two dates (in `B2` and `C2`) and in `B3` and `C3` use `=X+7` formula.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that would already make it easier is to not take W/Endings as a stable datum but the week number. Like in the Scandinavian countries, they actually count the week. For example now we are in week #12.
And if you really want to go more in details, then take it per day with 365 days.
With that settled, you should be able to do what you want. If you could show us what you're trying to solve with some sample code or a screenshot, I could probably help you more in details.